# Can I disable modules import (@import) in Google Cloud Messaging on iOS?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I've been trying to integrate GCM into my existing iOS project via Cocoapods. Upon building, I've been having compilation errors complaining about "@import errors..." with "...modules disabled". I do have modules enabled, except that the issue is happening since I have a mix of .m and .mm (Objective-C++) files where modules are not supported (this has already been raised by others).

I'm able to suppress the error in some files using the preprocessor flag "GMP_NO_MODULES" that's provided (e.g. in GGLInstanceID.h)

```
#if GMP_NO_MODULES
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#else
@import Foundation;
#endif
```

but other required header files (e.g. GGLConfiguration.h) do not have the flag built-in.

Did anyone find any short-term solutions around this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to fix this right now since there are internal files that do not seem to respect this flag. Although GCM folks are going to come up with an update to the library very soon, that should fix this.

Comment: Sadly, I realized the same thing and decided to go a different route, until the GCM folks fixes their library

Answer (score 0):

Why not adding GMP_NO_MODULES=1 in your Project or Target Preprocessor Macros?